# VisualSVN Server and Eclipse new repository setup

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server

How do I setup a new Repository Location in Eclipse for a VisualSVN Server repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a matter of entering the correct URL.

Note: The key thing to be aware of is you must enter the full path to the actual repository (project) and not the path only to the server root.
As per:
http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00011/
"Please note that Subversion clients cannot browse the list of available Subversion repositories. You can only browse the content of a repository."

So `http://mysvn/svn/myproject` and not So `http://mysvn/svn`